# How do I pass a DropDownList Value to a jQuery OnChange event? It's currently coming in null

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I just started learning MVC recently and I have run into a problem that may expose a fundamental misunderstanding I have with MVC. I currently have a model, and a ViewModel that is nothing more than a list of the models. The viewModel is passed into the view, and the model is the reference of the arrow function, in lieu of a property of the actual model being the reference for the arrow function. I believe this might be hindering me to get my actual model's properties from coming to the jQuery OnChange event for the DropDownList.

What I have initially accomplished is to be able to bring in a set of values to initially populate my dropdown lists (which works fine). Now, I want to give the user the option to pick an item on the dropdown list, and have it pull the unique row in the database associated to the selected value in the dropdown list, and fill other textboxes that match with the selected value.

I have so far tried many different properties in the AJAX call to pull from the DropDownList selectedvalue. Do I need to scrap my ViewModel altogether? If so, how would I initially populate the dropdowns? 
Model:

```
public class ReturnGoodsAuthorizationModel
{
    public string RGANumber { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    //TODO: Add additional columns here to return the rest of the ReturnGoodsAuthorization attributes
}
```

ViewModel:

```
    public class ReturnGoodsAuthorizationViewModel
    {
        public List<ReturnGoodsAuthorizationModel> ReturnGoodsAuthorizationModel { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function TestMethod() {
                            var selected_val = $('#inputCustomerNumber').text();
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: "/Home/SelectSBU",
                                data: "id=" + selected_val,
                                success: function (data) {
                                    if (data.length > 0) {
                                        $('#inputInvoiceNumber').val(data[0].CustomerNumber);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $('#inputInvoiceNumber').val('');
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    </script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="inputRGANumber">RGA Number</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ReturnGoodsAuthorizationModel, new SelectList(Model.ReturnGoodsAuthorizationModel,"RGANumber","RGANumber"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "inputRGANumber", @onchange = "TestMethod(this)" })

                            @*<label for="inputRGANumber">RGA Number</label>
                            <select id="inputRGANumber" class="form-control">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RGANumber, new SelectListItem(model.RGANumber, "Value", "Text"))
                        </div>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
private IReturnGoodsAuthorization returnGoodsAuthorization = new ReturnGoodsAuthorization();

public ActionResult ReturnGoodsAuthorization()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Return Goods Authorization";
    ViewBag.RGANumbers = new SelectList(returnGoodsAuthorization.GetAll());

    var returnGoodsAuthorizationViewModel = new ReturnGoodsAuthorizationViewModel
    {
        ReturnGoodsAuthorizationModel = returnGoodsAuthorization.GetAll()
    };

    return View(returnGoodsAuthorizationViewModel);
}
public JsonResult SelectSBU(string customerNumber)
{
    return Json(returnGoodsAuthorization.GetAll().Where(x => x.CustomerNumber == customerNumber), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

}
Repository:

```
public List<ReturnGoodsAuthorizationModel> GetAll()
{
    return this._db.Query<ReturnGoodsAuthorizationModel>(sql:"dbo.usp_ReturnGoodsAuthorization_Get",commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but I noticed in TestMethod you have var selected_val = $('#inputCustomerNumber').text(); but in your View there is no field with that ID.  Am I missing where it is?  Also, on the ReturnGoodsAuthorizationModel DropDownListFor, you have @onchange = "TestMethod(this)" but TestMethod is defined as not having a parameter, so you might want to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems by the looks of it.As @Doug F has said, you are calling a JavaScript function that does not take a parameter but you are passing it one, so it cannot find it.

The second is that this line here

```
var selected_val = $('#inputCustomerNumber').text();
```

I cannot see anywhere where this ID exists in the code. Is it meant to be

```
var selected_val = $('#inputRGANumber').text();
```

instead?